# Please, where can I find some good worked examples of compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Everywhere I have looked from the internet to books to my college notes I have not been able to find any fully worked solutions to showing more abstract sets are compact. It's obvious sets like (0,1] are not compact but what about more difficult sets like the set of bounded non-decreasing functions with the supremum metric ? Could anyone please link me to some pages that go through in detail how to solve more difficult problems like that ? I find it so much easier to learn by looking at completed proofs and trying to follow the logic!

Comment: There is no "general" method that works everywhere. There are some well known facts you should get familiar with: image of compact is compact, closed subset of compact is compact, product of compact is compact, etc. It is also a lot easier to show that spaces are not compact. In case of metric spaces simply by finding a sequence without converging subsequence. In your case of non-decreasing bounded functions you simply take a sequence $f_n=n$ of constant functions. This sequence cannot have a convergent subsequence because $\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert\geq 1$ for any $n\neq m$.

Comment: I believe Munkres has good excercise on compact and connected spaces

Comment: Honestly?  Here.

Comment: @freakish I'm not actually looking for a general method, rather I am looking for worked examples that will showcase the various ways one can show whether a set is compact so i can get a feel as to how to answer more difficult questions. Thank you for your solution to my specific example by the way, more examples like this is exactly the thing I'm looking for

Comment: @Randall obviously I know there are examples, but there are none ( at least that I have found ) that are FULLY worked examples

Comment: @PanchalShamsundar I quickly googled Munkres and found a book called topology second edition , Is this the book you were referring to ? I'm not sure if I can use it as I am only learning ( and studying for examination on) metric spaces and I believe there are some slight differences when proving compactness for either.

Comment: You could have a look at "Counterexamples in Topology", there are a lot of somewhat exotic examples in there for which compactness (and many many other properties) are discussed.

Comment: @LeonHendrian that's so funny, I took about ten books from the shelves to try and find good examples and I looked through nine of them before giving up and writing this question, the tenth was counter examples in topology XD thank you for your reccomendation I'll give it a look now, from a glance it seems like what im looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology. And in any handbook on general topology, very often after section about "paracompactness" or "completeness" or sth connected to compactness there are some counterexamples. If you are looking after non compact function spaces, then you can try "$C_p$ theory problem book" by Tkachuk.